# How to display the TypeScript class outline in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

When coding a TypeScript class Visual Studio (Pro 2012) gives me a class outline drop-down at the top left. You can see it in the screen shot.

[image]

Is there any way to have this displayed all the time? Like the Code Outline feature in FlashDevelop. I.e. docked to a window within VS so I can easily navigate to the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open Class View using the toolbar menu:

```
View > Class View
```

You can then view the contents of your classes, similar to that drop down, but docked wherever you like.

This doesn't currently show you the contents of a TypeScript file though - they aren't shown in the top list of classes.

[image: Class View - With Methods]

Comment: Bit confused, are you saying this will not be possible until VS2012 better supports TypeScript or can we force a .ts file into the view?

Comment: At present, this panel doesn't support TypeScript - I can find not way to configure it to do so. It is a good suggestion though, so perhaps mention it over on Codeplex: http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: That indeed is a real shame. TypeScript had much to go for it, and it has this boring grey IntelliSense popup right in the source code, but not having a full featured class view/graph is a real handicap.

Comment: lol almost a year later I did a new googeling but still the same results and ended up here. For me it is a handicap not having a real class view.

Answer (score 0):

While not the answer you're hoping for, a workaround is to develop your typescript files in WebStorm, and set up WebStorm's 'Remote Host' to be your Visual Studio project's IIS folder. Most often, I find that I have to push WebStorm changes to the Visual Studio project each time I test, but 'pure javascript' unit tests could be done purely on the webStorm side. You might also want to do early stage qunit testing using WebStorm's localhost server/port, perhaps with mocked data.